# removing <li> tags from wp_list_pages() using PHP

Tags: php, menus

as the title states, I am trying to remove the `<li></li>` tags from the list that gets generated with `wp_list_pages()`.

My thinking is to somehow run a for/foreach loop through the menu items and remove the `<li></li>` tags using `str_replace()`, but first I would need to parse the returned list into an array or something to traverse through the list items...

Any ideas on how I can accomplish that? or maybe a better way of going about it?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to remove them, but maybe it's easier to not generate them in the first place. The page list is displayed by a *Walker*. This is a class that "walks" over all the items in the tree, and displays them. [`wp_list_pages()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/post-template.php#L746) by default (via [`walk_page_tree()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/post-template.php#L876)) uses [the `Walker_Page` class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/classes.php#L1126), which displays everything in `<li>` elements. However, you can duplicate this class, remove everything it in you don't need, and pass that class to `wp_list_pages()` (with the `walker` argument).

Comment: Thanx for that, will definitely look into it!

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to create your own walker, simply use `str_replace(array('<li>', '</li>', '<ul>', '</ul>'), '', wp_list_pages('echo=0'));`

Comment: It probably should be a bit more advanced, because [the opening `<li>` has a variable `class` attribute](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/classes.php#L1205), and the opening `<ul>` has a fixed `class='children'` attribute.

Comment: the problem with a simple str_replace is the `wp_list_pages()` adds other content inside the `<li>` tag, such as class content

Comment: then remove them with regex: `preg_replace('@\<li([^>]*)>(.*?)@i', '$2', wp_list... )`

Answer (score 1):

Thanx for the answers guys, I've edited my answer to reflect Jan Fabry's comment about the `echo=0` argument, also thanx to One Trick Pony for pointing that out initially.

```
$lookfor = array('<li','</li>');
$replacewith = array('<div', '</div>');

$args = array(
    'echo'          => 0,
    'sort_column'   => 'menu_order',
    'title_li'      => __('')
);

$output = wp_list_pages( $args ); 

echo str_replace($lookfor,$replacewith,$output);
```

I will definitely look into creating a custom walker, as it seems to be the better way of achieving the result?

Thanx again for all your help!

Comment: @user2632: You don't need the output buffering if you use the `echo` argument of `wp_list_pages()`: if it is `false` the function will return the output instead of writing it itself.

Comment: Awesome, will give it a go, thanx for pointing that out!

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Thanx, that did the trick.

Comment: @user2632: Remember that the list also contains `<ul>` elements. And if you just want to replace them with `<div>` elements for styling, you can also adapt the stylesheet to cancel the default list-style for `<li>` elements, so they behave like any block element (as if they were just `<div>`'s). The Twenty Ten menu is a `<ul><li>` list, just styled with CSS to look different.

Comment: @Jan Fabry: I'm actually only trying to get pages with specific meta keys and values, and I've specified `'title_li'      => __('')` so right now there are no `<ul>` elements to remove, but thank you for pointing that out, it will definitely help later on if I add in multi level navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I used the strip_tags function:

```
$args = array('child_of' => $parent, 'echo' => false, 'title_li' => false, 'depth' => 0);

$output .= strip_tags(wp_list_pages($args), "<a>");
```