# Renaming wp_list_pages class

Tags: wp-list-pages

I am currently trying to change the outputted class that wp_list_pages is outputting. However, I don't wish to conduct a global change hence a simple filter is not an option i.e. Only this menu when generated by the shortcode should have a different class.

Currently, I'm producing my menu like this in the header.php:

```
<nav class="uk-navbar uk-navbar-attached" data-uk-sticky>
<ul class="uk-navbar-nav uk-width-1-1">
<?php do_shortcode('[top_main_menu]');?> 
</ul>
</nav>
```

In functions.php I have the following, noting I've tried two methods and neither work (Obviously I am not doing both at the same time)

```
/* Call using: [top_main_menu] */
add_shortcode( 'top_main_menu', 'echo_top_main_menu' );
function echo_top_main_menu() {

    //Doesn't work
    echo str_replace("page_item", "uk-hidden-small", wp_list_pages('echo=false&exclude=134,115,104&sort_column=menu_order&title_li='));

    //Doesn't work
    echo preg_replace('/li class\=\"/', 'li class="uk-hidden-small ', wp_list_pages('echo=false&exclude=134,115,104&sort_column=menu_order&title_li='));
}
```

Edit: Trial with filters. Updates class but effects all wp_list_pages instances, not just the one in the short code.

```
/* Call using: [top_main_menu] */
add_shortcode( 'top_main_menu', 'echo_top_main_menu' );
function echo_top_main_menu() {

    add_filter('wp_list_pages', create_function('$t', 'return str_replace("<li class=\"page_item", "<li class=\"uk-hidden-small ", $t);'));

    $output = wp_list_pages('echo=false&exclude=134,115,104&sort_column=menu_order&title_li=');

    remove_filter('wp_list_pages', create_function('$t', 'return str_replace("<li class=\"page_item", "<li class=\"uk-hidden-small ", $t);'));

    echo $output;
}
```

Currently, no matter what, the following it outputted on the menu:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-78"><a href="https://www.example.com/some-page/">Some Page</a></li>
```

However, I require:

```
<li class="uk-hidden-small page-item-78"><a href="https://www.example.com/some-page/">Some Page</a></li>
```

I'm aware a Walker is an option but surely the string return from wp_list_pages should be editable via string replace or similar?

Comment: A custom walker would be the "WP way" to accomplish this. Alternatively, it might be worth adjusting your CSS. For example instead of requiring the "uk-hidden-small" class on every individual <li> tag, you could put a class on the <ul> and style `ul.uk-hidden-small li { }` instead of `uk-hidden-small`.

Comment: You could also try saving wp_list_pages to a variable and then doing your str_replace. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9960/removing-li-tags-from-wp-list-pages-using-php#answer-9965

Comment: If a filter would work in this case, you can add it in the Shortcode and immediately remove it after calling `wp_list_pages`.

Comment: Updated answer with filter attempt, but not currently working.

I have a feeling my PHP functions are not firing e.g. str_replace. Could there be a permission issue to execute them? I tried WebElaine's answer, verbatim, and it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
/* Call using: [top_main_menu] */
add_shortcode( 'top_main_menu', 'echo_top_main_menu' );
function echo_top_main_menu() {

    $lookfor = array('page_item');
    $replacewith = array('uk-hidden-small');

    $args = array(
    'exclude' => '134,115,104',
    'echo'          => 0,
    'sort_column'   => 'menu_order',
    'title_li'      => __('')
    );

    $output = wp_list_pages( $args ); 

    echo str_replace($lookfor,$replacewith,$output);
}
```